# How to run Java SE applications in Cloud with CloudFoundry.com?

Tags: java, http, port, cloud-foundry

I am new to cloudfoundry.com and experimenting to deploy my existing Java SE based application server (a customized application web server running on port 5050). My application is not using any framework its plain Java SE JDK based application.

I am using eclipse with cloudfoundry plugin and deployed my application using the "Server View"(cloudfoundry.com instance) and I can see from the console that its running.

My questions are:

1. What is the URL for my application? Is it `http://<appname>.cloudfoundry.com`?
2. How to reach to my deployed application through the URL. I tried `http://<appname>.cloudfoundry.com`, `http://<appname>.cloudfoundry.com:5050`, but failed. I could find from forum that only 80 & 443 ports are opened for inbound tcp connection, so my next question is how to setup a rule so that HTTP requests to appname.cloudfoundry:80 get forwarded to my application at 5050 port?
3. How to setup a rule so that `appname.cloudfoundry:80` gets forwarded to my application at 5050 port? Is it possible?
4. I have some static page templates & css files which are required for my application to generate dynamic pages and then stores them temporarily, is it possible? If yes how to store the static pages along with the application? and how to create files?
5. I understand that outgoing TCP requests are also restricted to 80 & 443 ports, if I have requirement to connect to 8080 or any other port, what is the way out?

Answer (score 3):

here are some answers for you :

1. will be whatever you choose (provided that  is available, *ie* not already taken by some other apps)
2. You need to modify your app, in particular the http server part of your app, so that it binds to the port and hostname that Cloud Foundry allocated for you. More specifically, Cloud Foundry advertises two environment variables for that purpose : `VCAP_APP_PORT` and `VCAP_APP_HOST` (chances are you don't need to worry about the latter). A very good read would be http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/ which uses tomcat as an example. If you want to access env variables from Java code (as opposed to from the shell, as the blog post does) you'll need System.getEnv().
3. This will work automatically provided you did 2)
4. There is currently no support for plain static files. You could however

   1. Have your http server handle them
   2. If acceptable, use another app on Cloud Foundry to serve them. This is really easy using eg Sinatra, as my colleague Andy explains [here](http://andypiper.co.uk/2012/08/21/a-simple-website-on-cloud-foundry/).
5. IIRC, the only restriction for outbound connection is port 25 to prevent mail spamming. So you should be good. See http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20951826-cloudfoundry-com-faq

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! You answered all my queries. Only problem for me is to use Sinatra bcoz I have loads of logic in Java which uses static templates from file system (html,css,js) for generating the dynamic web pages and then stores/caches them till the session lasts and as I'm not skilled in ruby & sinatra, don't know how to bridge the java file system access for my static contents with sinatra project.

Comment: Regarding 4, Is it possible to use volatile filesystem for read & write? 
If yes, 
 a) How can I push files to my deployed standalone app through eclipse plugin or through any other tool? 
 b) What would be the path for the pushed files for accessing it from my Java app? 
 c) What env variables/paths could be used for creating volatile files from my Java app? 
 d) Are there any limit on size?

Comment: Ok, so I would recommend to stick to using your app indeed. You do have access to the filesystem, only gotcha is that as you said it is volatile. meaning that it goes away when the app restarts. Recommended practice is to look at java.io.tmpdir or use APIs like File.createTempFile(). Current free account limit is 2Gb for all your files (logs included)

Comment: Thanks @ebottard I could setup my application server on CF. I have another application server which uses **two socket listening port numbers**, my question is _how to map individual public URLs with different port numbers?_

Comment: You can't. You'll need to create two apps for that, and maybe coordinate their state through a service of some sort (be it a DB or RabbitMQ). HTH